# Despite of log.retention.hours=168 the log files of messages sent yesterday are not present

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, retention

yesterday I installed Kafka 2.0 in my Ubuntu 18.04.01 Server Edition and followed the QuickStart instructions and explanations till successfully deploying the Step 7 : https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

Today I discovered that there are no kafka-logs- files  in /tmp , despite being directly explicitated in the related server.properties files:

```
server.properties :
# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
 log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.hours=168

 server-1.properties :
# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs-1
# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.hours=168

server-2.properties :
# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs-2
# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.hours=168
```

Why did it happen, despite of the successfull follow-up of the first seven steps of the QuickStart tutorial? And what to do in order to keep the Kafka Log files, which contain the messages sent between the producers and the receivers through Kafka brokerage?

Looking forward to your kind help.
Marco

Comment: /tmp is cleaned on reboot and is a very wrong place to store kafka logs. Did you reboot your computer ?

Comment: Hi @Gery . Yes I did reboot my computer. Does it mean that the instructions in https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart saying "log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs-1" could be extended in explaining that for longer storage of Kafka logs another directory could be better?

Answer (score 0):

Since your `log.dirs` is pointing to `/tmp` directory, it will wipe everything on system reboot.  Same applies for Zookeeper `data.dir` also.

Make sure that these directories are not pointing to the `tmp` folder.

Also, there is one more attribute `log.retention.bytes` along with `log.retention.hours` which is useful for log compaction.

It denotes the maximum size of logs before deleting it. By default, it is -1. Hence logs can be retained based on retention time.  If it is configured to any specific numbers, beyond that it will delete the logs.